# Advanced Merchant Integration(AIM) in ror with authorize.net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorize.net

I am using gem 'authorize-net', '~> 1.5.2' in my site. Payment process is working fine as per given details on this link https://github.com/joevandyk/authorize-net

Problem is I want to add CVV number in these payment system. It only take card number and card expiry month and year.

How can I add these CVV numbers to  this process?

Comment: [anyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/104307/anyone) is a user on another stack exchange site,  so the answer to your original question was "No" (she cannot say) or "Yes" (she can say). Yes/No answerable questions (easily checked) are almost always uninteresting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [docs][1] it looks like you can use the `card_code` attribute.

```
AuthorizeNet::CreditCard.new('4111111111111111', '1120', card_code: 900)
```

Comment: Can you say me how can we set gate in this process to live I have done this  transaction = AuthorizeNet::AIM::Transaction.new(@authorze_net_api_key, @authorze_net_transaction_key, :gateway => @authorze_net_mode) where @authorze_net_mode=:production